# Hyphenate a word that contains a diacritic used in Romanian writing

Tags: babel, hyphenation

The words are `ilocuționare` and `funcțiile`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{i-lo-cu-ți-o-na-re func-ți-i-le}
\begin{document}

ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare ilocuționare 
funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile funcțiile 



\end{document}
```

```
\hyphenation{i-lo-cu-ți-o-na-re func-ți-i-le}
```

Writing them with diacritics gives me error. (`! Improper \hyphenation will be flushed.`)

[image]

Comment: Did you use the relevant language option of babel andt the T1 font encoding?

Comment: I use `[romanian]{babel}` and `[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: What happens if you also run `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, as already asked by @Bernard?

Comment: I get the same error. I updated the main post with error pic

Comment: I get the error as seen in pic. If I type the word without diacritics (and change also in hyphenation) the word is hyphen, with diacritics I have that error.

Comment: Which font, or font family, do you employ?

Comment: No font at all. Just [T1]{fontenc} now (which I dont like it since it is pixelate - btw)

Comment: If you get pixelate fonts, something else that's not quite right would appear to be afflicting your TeX distrution. For sure, loading the `fontenc` package with the option `T1` should *not*, by itself, cause the pixelated appearance.

Comment: @Mafsi In order for hyphenation to work correctly, you need a font encoding which includes all letters of the word. I don't think that any LaTeX encoding has `ț`, therefore the best approach is to switch to LuaLateX (or XeLateX) which have Unicode encoded fonts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The T1 font encoding doesn't unfortunately support Romanian. It has just 256 available slots for characters and when it was devised other choices were made.

The idea was that other font encodings would have appeared in order to cover other variants of the Latin alphabet. Romanian is in good company: Maltese, Latvian and Lithuanian, among European languages, are not fully supported. No alternative encoding was devised and, even if it is now, fonts should be rebuilt to support it.

The comma below diacritic for Ș and Ț are only available as built characters, which has the consequence that TeX cannot hyphenate a word past them and it's not possible to specify them neither in hyphenation patterns nor in `\hyphenation`.

So this is not a problem with `babel`.

On the other hand, Unicode contains the characters U+0218, U+0219, U+021A and U+021B in the Latin Extended-B block. The hyphenation patterns for Romanian contain them, but this means that a Unicode-aware engine has to be used, so you should go with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

There may be a shortcoming in the pdfLaTeX-based implementation of Romanian `babel`. Fortunately, compiling a basic test document under LuaLaTex seems to work just fine.

[image]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\addto\extras{romanian}{\hyphenation{i-lo-cu-ți-o-na-re func-ți-i-le}}
\AtBeginDocument{\lefthyphenmin1 \righthyphenmin2} % defaults are '2' and '3', resp.

% Just for this example:
\setlength\textwidth{1sp} 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
ilocuționare funcțiile
\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated the main post with a MWE. That MWE is not working in PDFLatex. It works only in LuaLaTeX as @Marcel Kruger segested

Comment: how can i fix this in `babel`? To whom should I address the issue?

Comment: @Mafsi - You might contact Javier Bezos, the maintainer of the `babel` package. Unfortunately, I don't have an email address for him. However, he regularly frequents this site, so there's a good chance that he'll notice your posting.

Comment: @Mico It's not a `babel` problem.

Comment: @mico, babel is on github: https://github.com/latex3/babel (although this is not a babel bug, it seems)